# Find the word in the stream?

Tags: string, algorithm, recursion

Given an infinite stream of characters and a list L of strings, create a function that calls an external API when a word in L is recognized during the processing of the stream.

Example: 
L = ["ok","test","one","try","trying"]

stream = a,b,c,o,k,d,e,f,t,r,y,i,n,g.............

The call to external API will happen when 'k' is encountered, again when the 'y' is encountered, and again at 'g'.

My idea:
Create trie out of the list and navigate the nodes as you read from stream in linear time. But there would be a bug if you just do simple trie [search](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/trie-insert-and-search/).

Assume you have words "abxyz" and "xyw" and your input is "abxyw".In this case you can't recognize "xyw" with trie.

So search should be modified as below:

let's take above use case "abxyw". We start the search and we find we have all the element till 'x'. Moment you get 'x' you have two options:

1. Check if the current element is equal to the head of trie and if it is equal to head of trie then call recursive search.
2. Continue till the end of current word. In this case for your given input it will return false but for the recursive search we started in point 1, it will return true.

Below is my modified search but I think it has bugs and can be improved. Any suggestions?

```
#define SIZE 26
struct tri{
    int complete;
    struct tri *child[SIZE];
};

void insert(char *c, struct tri **t)
{
    struct tri *current = *t;
    while(*c != '\0')
    {
        int i;
        int letter = *c - 'a';
        if(current->child[letter] == NULL) {
            current->child[letter] = malloc(sizeof(*current));
            memset(current->child[letter], 0, sizeof(struct tri));
        }
        current = current->child[letter];
        c++;
    }
    current->complete = 1;
}

struct tri *t;
int flag = 0;
int found(char *c, struct tri *tt)
{
    struct tri *current = tt;

    if (current == NULL)
        return 0;
    while(*c != '\0')
    {
        int i;
        int letter = *c - 'a';
        /* if this is the first char then recurse from begining*/
        if (t->child[letter] != NULL)
            flag = found(c+1, t->child[letter]);
        if (flag == 1)
            return 1;
        if(!flag && current->child[letter] == NULL) {
            return 0;
        }
        current = current->child[letter];
        c++;
    }
    return current->complete;
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    t = malloc(sizeof(*t));
    t->complete = 0;
    memset(t, 0, sizeof(struct tri));

    insert("weathez", &t);
    insert("eather", &t);
    insert("weather", &t);
    (1 ==found("weather", t))?printf("found\n"):printf("not found\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is exactly what [Aho-Corasick algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm) does.

You can take a look at my Aho-Corasick implementation. It's contest-oriented, so maybe not focused on readability but I think it's quite clear:

```cpp
typedef vector<int> VI;

struct Node {
  int size;
  Node *fail, *output;
  VI id;
  map<char, Node*> next;
};

typedef pair<Node*, Node*> P;
typedef map<char, Node*> MCP;

Node* root;

inline void init() {
  root = new Node;
  root->size = 0;
  root->output = root->fail = NULL;
}

Node* add(string& s, int u, int c = 0, Node* p = root) {
  if (p == NULL) {
    p = new Node;
    p->size = c;
    p->fail = p->output = NULL;
  }
  if (c == s.size()) p->id.push_back(u);
  else {
    if (not p->next.count(s[c])) p->next[s[c]] = NULL;
    p->next[s[c]] = add(s, u, c + 1, p->next[s[c]]);
  }
  return p;
}

void fill_fail_output() {
  queue<pair<char, P> > Q;
  for (MCP::iterator it=root->next.begin();
       it!=root->next.end();++it)
    Q.push(pair<char, P> (it->first, P(root, it->second)));
  while (not Q.empty()) {
    Node *pare = Q.front().second.first;
    Node *fill = Q.front().second.second;
    char c = Q.front().first; Q.pop();
    while (pare != root && !pare->fail->next.count(c))
      pare=pare->fail;
    if (pare == root) fill->fail = root;
    else fill->fail = pare->fail->next[c];
    if (fill->fail->id.size() != 0) 
      fill->output = fill->fail;
    else fill->output = fill->fail->output;
    for (MCP::iterator it=fill->next.begin();
         it!=fill->next.end();++it)
        Q.push(pair<char,P>(it->first,P(fill,it->second)));
  }
}

void match(int c, VI& id) {
  for (int i = 0; i < id.size(); ++i) {
    cout << "Matching of pattern " << id[i];
    cout << " ended at " << c << endl;
  }
}

void search(string& s) {
  int i = 0, j = 0;
  Node *p = root, *q;
  while (j < s.size()) {
    while (p->next.count(s[j])) {
      p = p->next[s[j++]];
      if (p->id.size() != 0) match(j - 1, p->id);
      q = p->output;
      while (q != NULL) {
        match(j - 1, q->id);
        q = q->output;
      }
    }
    if (p != root) {
      p = p->fail;
      i = j - p->size;
    }
    else i = ++j;
  }
}

void erase(Node* p = root) {
  for (MCP::iterator it = p->next.begin(); 
       it != p->next.end(); ++it)
    erase(it->second);
  delete p;
}

int main() {
  init();
  int n;
  cin >> n;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    string s;
    cin >> s;
    add(s, i);
  }
  fill_fail_output();
  string text;
  cin >> text;
  search(text);
  erase(root);
}
```

Comment: nice one but i am after my recursive solution. I just want to know if that is wrong or does it have a corner case which i have not take care of.

Comment: I am marking this answer as correct just because it tells you the right algorithm but the original question was different.